# Configure entity with 2 properties of its own type using Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a class, called Process, that has 1 property which points to a parent of the current process and another property which is a list of children of the current process. Both properties are Process type again.

```
public class Process
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int? ParentId { get; set; }
     public Process Parent { get; set; }

     public List<Process> Children { get; set; }

     // Nodes of the Process
     public List<WfModelItem> Nodes { get; set; }   // added 
}

public class WfModelItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ProcessId { get; set; }
    public Process Process  { get; set; }
}
```

When a process has no parent, its ParentId is `null` and each process can have some children as well.

I configure it like below:

```
public class ProcessConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Process>
{
    public ProcessConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(c => c.Children)
            .WithMany();
        this.HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
            .WithMany();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when i want to add it to db by `dbContext.Processes.Add(aProcess)`, i get this error:

> A relationship cannot be established from property 'Parent' on type 'Process' to property 'Parent' on type 'Process'. Check the values in the InversePropertyAttribute to ensure relationship definitions are unique and reference from one navigation property to its corresponding inverse navigation property

How can i correctly configure the Process class? Thanks.

***Update:***
I added another property in `Process` class to sure that the problem is fully described.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
this
.HasMany(oj => oj.Children)
.WithOne(j => j.Parent)
.HasForeignKey(j => j.ParentId );
```

Or

```
public class Process
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long? ParentID { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Children")]
    public Process Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Process> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `HasMany(u => u.Children)` doesn't accept `HasForeignKey(u => u.ID)`

Comment: @ehsantoghian can you retry with the answer updated pls ?

Comment: @Thiery-v I edited the configuration (fluent api solution).  The `HasMany()` doesn't accept the `WithOne()`. I tried the `WithOptional()` and `WithRequired()`. but both of them created this error: `Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'WfModelItem_Process_Target' of the relationship 'Process' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.`

Answer (score 0):

After two days investigation, i've found the solution. I post it for further readers. As i explained in the question each **Process** can have several nodes and child processes, so its possible for a node to belong to a process and its child. When this scenario happens, the entity framework complains about the `'WfModelItem_Process_Source'` and raises below exception:

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'WfModelItem_Process_Source' of the relationship '…' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

To fix the issue, i changed the ***WfModelItem*** class as below:

```
public class WfModelItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Process> Processes  { get; set; }
}
```

and changed the configuration classes :

```
public class WfModelItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<WfModelItem>
{
    public WfModelItemConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(n => n.Processes)
            .WithMany(p => p.Nodes);
    }
}

public class ProcessConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Process>
{
    public ProcessConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(oj => oj.Children)
            .WithOptional(j => j.Parent)
            .HasForeignKey(j => j.ParentId);

        this.HasMany(n => n.Nodes)
            .WithMany(p => p.Processes);

        this.HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentId);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.